# Counting numbers in Functional Programming Style?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm trying to understand the concept of functional programming. I'm just using javascript here to understand the concepts of it

Usually we would count to 10 in this way :

```js
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
 console.log(i+1)
}
```

is this the Functional Programming Equivalent?

```js
var a = 1;
var n = 10;

function counter(){
  console.log(a);
  if(a<n){
    counter(++a);
  }
}

counter();
```

Comment: `++a` is not something you would do with functional programming

Comment: You've got an example of recursion there.  If you want to understand FP, you might want to try a more functional language like Clojure.

Comment: Haskell is a pure functional language.

Comment: A little help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37242112/1636522.

Comment: No, replacing a loop statement with a function that neither takes an argument nor returns a value isn't functional at all. You merely mimic imperative statements with functions. FP is a completely different approach and it takes a lot of time to comprehend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursion to get a (more) functional programming solution:

```js
(function counter(a, n){
    console.log(a);
    a < n && counter(a+1, n);
})(1, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it.

`Array(n).fill()` is used to generate a range of `n` element to iterate over.

`.forEach(...)` iterates through the elements and does the work based on element's `index` and the `b` ("base") value provided from the outside.

```js
const counter = (n, b) => Array(n).fill().forEach((_, index) => console.log(index + b));

counter(10, 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't change mutable data in functional programming. Think of it as doing math in school when you have to solve for a variable. No matter what you do, that variable will always have the same value. In your example, you are changing the value of that variable. To do functional programming, that variable needs to have the same value when that function ends as it did in the beginning.

```js
var a = 1;
var n = 10;

counter(a,n);

function counter(num, limit){
  if (num > limit) 
    return;
  console.log(num);
  counter(num+1, limit);
}
```

Would be considered functional programming as a and n would still have the same value and thus you have not changed mutable data.

[Functional Programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)

Comment: "You can't change mutable data" is contradictory. I would say "in functional programming, data is immutable".

Comment: Yes, but a var is a mutable variable in JavaScript. So even though you can change it, you need to treat it like it's immutable.

Comment: Still, your sentence is ambiguous. Keep in mind that you are talking to newbies.